# How can I create one more partition?

Tags: 13.04, partitioning, gparted

[image]

- sda1 -> Windows XP
- sda2 -> Windows 7
- sda3 -> Data Partition

I have created 4 primary partitions, I have 7xx GB left, how can I create one more partition?

Comment: I think you could expand sda4 to occupy the unallocated space, and than create a secondary partition

Comment: @Wouter I would love to, but please guide me how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To most "logical" thing you can do is:

1. Expand your 4th and last **Primary Partition** (sda4) which is an
   **Extended Partition** (which merely serves as a container for **Logical Partitions**) so as to include the unallocated space at the end.
2. Then create another **Logical Partition** (or more) at the end of sda4.

However, you can only do this if and when the Extended Partition is (i.e. sda5 and sda6 are) **not mounted**.

Therefore, I would suggest you use an **Ubuntu** (or any other Linux, e.g. **Parted Magic**) **Live CD/DVD/USB** to boot your computer for this purpose.

Comment: If I booted the system using Live CD, is it too difficult to do this, I really don't know much about Linux?

Comment: If I booted the system using Live CD, is there any GUI tool for the job?

Comment: One more question, what is appropriate swap partition size? I have 8GB of RAM, I have watched System Monitor for several times, the system never use the swap.

Comment: @Kongthap: I strongly recommend you to use a **Parted Magic Live CD/USB**, which you can easily boot your PC with, and start **GParted Partition Manager** there. You will also find **Clonezilla** very very useful which allows you to create backups of your entire disk or individual partitions for recovery purposes.

Comment: @Kongthap: There are various suggestions about optimum swap size, which I find a bit too complicated (Perhaps you can also search the Internet ;-) After some reading I've personally decided to keep it equal to my RAM size, which is 4GB, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I have a progress, please help me answer further question at [This Topic](http://askubuntu.com/questions/349987/do-i-have-to-move-swap-partition-the-right)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want the partition for you could extend sda4 and create another partition in there. It looks like that is your Ubuntu installation so you could create that as a big data area for Ubuntu. You can even mount it as your /home partition. Having a separate home partition can be helpful when upgrading.

To add the partition to sda4:

Select sda4 and extend it to the end of the drive. Now the 753GB of unallocated space in inside your extended partition sda4. Now you can format it to ext4 and you have yourself another partition (most likely labeled sda7). You can access this partition by mounting it.

To mount new partition:

make a directory to mount it `cd ~ && mkdir bigData`

In Ubuntu terminal type `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`

In this file add the line: `/dev/sda7 /home/<username>/bigData ext4 defaults 0  0`

Now this partition will automatically be mounted when the system starts.

To mount it without restarting the system type `mount /dev/sda7`

If your not a fan of that solution your only other option is some serious rearranging which could cause errors and prevent your system from booting. Be careful and backup your data before attempting.

Comment: What you meant is "I can extend the unallocated space to sda4"???, if so please guide me how to do that, if possible I would love to extend it as sda7 (inside sda4).

Comment: I hope, I did not misunderstand.

Comment: You can extend sda4 to the end of the drive. Then you will be able to format the unallocated space within sda4.

Comment: I really don't know much about Linux, do I have to boot my PC using Live CD to avoid mouting of sda5, sda6???