# Do I have to move swap partition to the right side?

Tags: 13.04, gparted

[image]

According to [This Topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/349956/how-can-i-create-one-more-partition/349965?noredirect=1#comment448408_349965) I just expand my sda4 to include unallocated space, my question is after create 2 new partitions sda7, sda8, do I need to move the swap partition to the most right of the disk? (I really don't know this, I saw [a clip on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDgUwWkvuIY) which moving the swap partition to the right side)

Thanks.

Comment: sda4 is an extended partition, it holds other partitions.  Assuming you are expanding the ext4 partition, then to expand sda5, you will have to turn off your SWAP, them move it to the right, then expand sda5.  But you can't expand sda5 while your system is on, so boot to a Live environment and resize through that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**You don't have to, but...**

Although having the Swap partition at the end might not affect performance, it might let you modify the other partitions (enlarge/reduce etc.) **more easily** later without touching your Swap again.

And to do this in **GParted**:

1. Select sda6, **Right-click > Swapoff** (to unmount the swap partition so that you can perform operations on it)
2. Delete Swap (sda6) partition, which will create a larger unallocated space at the end of sda4
3. Create one or more partitions as you need and then re-create the Swap partition at the end.

Comment: Should the newly created partition be "Swapped on" as in right-click swap on in the end?

Comment: @AmoghJoshi Yes, it's advisable to turn the Swap on again in order to let the system make use of it immediately. For it might cause problems in some cases if the system operates without a swap partition, although it will automatically turn it on during reboot.

Answer (score 3):

No, the swap partition does **not need to be at the end of the disk.**

The location also does not affect performance to an amount that is worth mentioning. See this topic for more information about how the placement of the swap partition affects your system:
[Is having the 'swap' partition at the 'beginning' better than at the 'end'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56883/is-having-the-swap-partition-at-the-beginning-better-than-at-the-end)